# Query being run multiple times

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to run the following code in PHP to query a MongoDB:

```
<?

$m = new Mongo(); // connect

$dogs = $m->dogs;
$races = $dogs->newdogs;

$js = "function() {
    return this.location == 'SHEFFIELD'
}";

$dataSet = $races->find(array('$where' => $js));

foreach ($dataSet as $r){

}

?>
```

When I run this and watch the console, I see the query being run once.

When I change the foreach loop to be nested within another one like this:

```
foreach(range(1,5) as $test){
    foreach ($dataSet as $r){

    }
}
```

I see the query being run 7 times in the console?
Is this something stupid I am doing? A scoping issue? Or am I just misunderstanding how MongoDB is supposed to work?

Thanks
AH

Comment: Why use `$where` instead of `$races->find(array('location' => 'SHEFFIELD'));` ? using `$where` on it's own, forces a full scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `$dataSet` is a [`MongoCursor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php), not an array. A `MongoCursor` is a representation of a query. It will be turned into an array "on-demand", that means that when you use `foreach` on it, `$dataSet` is converted into an array by simply querying.

Since you do it within another loop, the `MongoCursor` is executed every time it encounters the `foreach`. If you don't want that behaviour, you can use [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.iterator-to-array.php), since a `MongoCursor` is just an iterator:

```
$executed = iterator_to_array($dataSet); // Actual query execution
foreach($executed as $r) {               // Iterate the array, not the iterator
    // Hic sunt ponies
}
```

**EDIT**: Keep in mind that `iterator_to_array` converts the entire result set into an array in memory. If you have a very big result set, this can cause huge and unnecessary memory consumption. It's advisable to stick with a single `foreach` call, since it will only load one single row into memory at once.